# iPhone online login system

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I am trying to create a login system for my iPhone application. My login system is not an ordinary one. Here is what I want the iphone to do.

First of all I will post to a website 
"https://www.example.com/login" 
my username and password.
If login is achieved (i.e. username and password are correct), it will redirect me to
 "https://www.example.com/login/success" 
else it will redirect me to 
"https://www.example.com/login/retry".
I know it sounds strange but thats the way it works. By the way my application is programmed using Objective-C.
So what I want from the login system is to detect the address of the redirected site and if it is the success one, it will allow me to view the rest of the application.

Can I do that login system on iOS? Do you have any idea about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NSHTTPURLResponse` class has a method [`allHeaderFields`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPURLResponse_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSHTTPURLResponse/allHeaderFields) that you can use to pull out the `Location` header.  Be aware that header names are case-insensitive.

Comment: Can you expand on that please? How can I use that?

Comment: If you aren't familiar with making HTTP calls in iOS, read [URL Loading System Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html).

Comment: perfect, I will go through that and see what I can do

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to use the actual website for authentication. While this may be possible, I would advise against it. You should write a separate web service (aka an API) for the app to interact with. If you aren't familiar with the concept of an API do a quick google search.

Comment: yeap I will use the actual website for the authentication. This is because they do not give me access to the database, for security reasons. Therefore I have to do it that way. Can I do that using an API?

Comment: You could write an API that authenticates on the website and returns success/error depending upon where the website redirects. I prefer to leave as much work as possible to the API. That way, say for example the login urls change (i.e. valid login goes to /success2). You could now just rework your API instead of having to send out a whole new build of your iPhone app (which would now be broken).